# AngularJS Http vs Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

i'm trying to send to a ws a post request using some parameters.

in Ajax i do:

```
$.post("http://myWS",{name:"xxx",surname:"yyy"},function(response){
   console.log(response);
});
```

this generate that payload:

```
{name:"xx",surname:"yyy"}
```

In AngularJS i do:

```
return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    async : true,
    cache : false,
    url: "http://myWS",
    data: {name:"xxx",surname:"yyy"},
});
```

And this generates that paylaod:

```
{"name":"xxx","surname":"yyy"}
```

As you can see this payload differs from ajax one.

I tried to add header to $http request:

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

but results is the same.

what could be the problem??
thanks!

Comment: The angular.js request payload seems to be valid JSON, in contrast to the payload of the jQuery Ajax call.

Comment: that is not output but request payload

Comment: Thats want I meant. Sorry.

Comment: valid JSON is the ajax one not the angularjs one

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ will tell you the exact otherwise ;-)

Comment: The query version is accepted by many JSON parsers, but if you are very strict about the syntax it is wrong.

Comment: i need ajax one. how can i do?

Comment: Go yell at whoever is only accepting invalid JSON ;-) As a work-around you could create string that match the invalid JSON by on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved setting headers and params in this way:

```
return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    async : true,
    cache : false,
    url: "http://myWS",
    data: $.param({name:"xxx",surname:"yyy"}),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
});
```